# Titanium Tab.open transition

Tags: titanium

When I'm opening a window in a tab, the slide animation is by default from right to left. I need to change it to left to right.

```
myapp.mainTab.open(window)
```

Is there any way how I can pass a different transition?

Answer (score 0):

you could try like it is mentioned [in the example](https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/examples/transitions.js#L53):

```
myWindow.open({transition:Titanium.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.CURL_DOWN});
```

the transitions are specified [here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.iPhone-module). in general you should pass your own animation to open.

Comment: This doesn't work for tab.open(). I'm suspecting that tabs animate windows only with a default slide and you can't change it